# How to click a button type through selenium using Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Following is the HTML code of the button I was trying to click:

```
<div class="login-button">
    <button type="submit" class="btn login-from-btn">Login</button>
</div>
```

What are the possible ways that I can click that button using either XPath/Class Name/CSS Selector?

I have tried as follows:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("login-button btn login-from-btn").click()
```

Comment: What is the result when you run your code as it is?

Comment: Nothing is happening, no action is being performed on the button

Comment: Is there an error, or it just doesn't do anything?

Comment: have you tried `driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn login-from-btn")[0].click()`?

Comment: @RatmirAsanov - Ur's answer is working fine. Thank You soo much.

Comment: @NotAnAmbiTurner- It's not working. I've already tried this one.

Answer (score 0):

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Login']")

can you try this one and let me know does it working